# Laravel 8 - Eager loading inconsistent behavior

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I've these 2 classes

TransaccionWebPay.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TransaccionWebPay extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'TRANSACCION_WEBPAY';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_TRANSACCION_WEBPAY';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public static function getByTokenWS($tokenws)
    {
        return TransaccionWebPay::where("TOKEN_WS", "=", $tokenws)->first();
    }

    public function detalle()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TransaccionPresupuesto::class,"ID_TRANSACCION_WEBPAY");
    }
}
```

TransaccionPresupuesto.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Payments\PresupuestoPendiente;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TransaccionPresupuesto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'TRANSACCION_WEBPAY_PRESUPUESTO';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_TRANSACCION_WEBPAY_PRESUPUESTO';
    
    public function presupuesto(){
        return $this->hasOne(PresupuestoPendiente::class,"ID_PRESUPUESTO","ID_PRESUPUESTO");
    }
    
}
```

it happens that, when I try to eager load TransaccionWebPay using

```php
$response = TransaccionWebPay::with(['detalle'])
                ->where("TOKEN_WS", "=", $id)
                ->first();
```

detalle has not records (which is wrong)

however, if I do

```php
$response = TransaccionWebPay->where("TOKEN_WS", "=", $id)->first();
$detalle = $response->detalle // there are records! (and this is the expected behavior)
```

Note: it works for some records and it does not for others. which is very strange.
when I do debug the query, I notice that this happens when "with" does not work

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `TRANSACCION_WEBPAY` where `TOKEN_WS` = ? limit 1"
    "bindings" => array:1 [
      0 => "1131f9a53xxx"
    ]
    "time" => 1.52
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "query" => "select * from `TRANSACCION_WEBPAY_PRESUPUESTO` where `TRANSACCION_WEBPAY_PRESUPUESTO`.`ID_TRANSACCION_WEBPAY` in (0)"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 1.07
  ]
]
```

regarding to the second query... I'm not sure why eloquent is querying  "TRANSACCION_WEBPAY_PRESUPUESTO`.`ID_TRANSACCION_WEBPAY` in (0)". did I missed anything?

I'm struggling to find why if I'm making some mistake to define the relationships or if missed something.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe there is some problem here - public function presupuesto(){
        return $this->hasOne(PresupuestoPendiente::class,"ID_PRESUPUESTO","ID_PRESUPUESTO");
    }  The same id is repeated twice.

Comment: Nope. Is not that :/